# Classloader does not look 'outside' maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, reflection

In a maven module with no dependencies to maven module X I am trying to load a class from module X. Is this possible? I cant add a dependency (cycle) and reflection is necessary in my case.

With FilesUtils I can find de files, no issues here. However then I try to run some tests to find out if I can load a class<?> with a path but no results so far.

Both Classloader and URLClassloader get instansiated within my maven module and the following did not work.

```
urls = new URL[]{
                new File("biz-test/target/classes").toURI().toURL(),
                new File("biz/target/test-classes").toURI().toURL(),
            };
Classloader cl = new URLClassloader(urls);
```

Also tried Class.forName in multiple ways (complete path, replacing linux / with ., class only, package path only)

I read about google reflections library, but this is a very large library? Any disadvantages to this?

My last option will be to move this generator to a module that can acces all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Can you explain that more in detail: ` I cant add a dependency (cycle)` That means your setup is wrong or the code has to be. refactored into separate module...

Comment: Seems very much like an XY problem. What you are attempting seems likely to be completely wrong. It would be worth elaborating on this: "*I cant add a dependency (cycle)*". Cycle where? Your code depends on Module X and Module X also depends on your code? Why would that ever happen? What are the 2 modules supposed to do? "*and reflection is necessary in my case*" Necessary why? For what?

Comment: That cycle is correct, I should investigate that more. Module x should not be dependend on a module that hold devTools. I was accepting it too quickly. 

Reflection because because I make a connection with a db for the meta data that tells me what classes to load and what 'rules' to follow

Comment: *That comment about the cycle is correct, the cycle isnt ;)

Seems that a module is misusing this tool module so this seems to be the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a cyclic dependency, you need to refactor your code. You either need to merge  two modules into one or you need to create a common dependency for both modules.

Trying to trick around cyclic dependencies by using classloader or reflection is the wrong approach.